# Why are there nails only half way in, in my garage?

Tags: drywall, garage, nails

I'm going to be painting my garage walls this weekend as part of a project to turn it into a home gym.

As I'm working on the walls, I noticed a lot of nails that are halfway in.

Is this on purpose? Should I pull them out? Or hammer them in? Or leave as is?

*Home was built in the 70's. We moved in two years ago.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One of the things I do to every new dwelling I occupy is a purge of odd hanging hardware (because I like to start fresh and because they're a danger to my eyeballs and shoulders). One old garage I owned must've had 500 nails, screws, hooks, and other whatnot stuck everywhere. It's an afternoon project!

Answer (score 15):

People were using them to secure things or hang things on.  They serve no purpose.  I would just pull them out since hammering them in probably will not be that easy.  You might want to get a small board to press against so you do no damage drywall.

Also FYI I do not think the drywall that is currently on there is going to take pain - even primer - that well.

Comment: Why not? And what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @YL - There were two types of drywall openly used in the US (sorry I don't know their official names) that people used in the late 60s - late 80s for garages.   Neither has a "face" on it to paint - one is a dull yellowish brown and you have the shiny type.   Neither holds paint well at all.   I would test a small area with a good primer.   You might need to try an oil based primer too.   But test the primer out before you commit to it, as I am not sure you are going to get much to hold to it well- it will look like it is painting it but the brown will show through as the paint doesn't bind.

Comment: You might have some luck with Zinsser BIN as a primer.

Comment: I recently painted my garage that looked exactly like that. I used a Sherwin-Williams “sealing” primer and it worked just fine. Though, I did need to spray on some shellac in a few stained locations.

Comment: Deglosser might work - I think I've used "Klean-Strip 1 qt. Liquid Sandpaper Cleaner & Deglosser". You paint it on, and then paint over it.

Comment: Ended up using a primer and two coats of paint. I'll check again over the next few days to see how it came out but so far looks ok (considering you can still see all the nails that hold the drywall, etc)

Comment: Update: primer and two coats of paint did the job. It doesn't look at good a a finished interior wall inside the house, of course, but the paint was able to hide all the usual marks on the drywall. The question remains how long the paint itself will hold... we'll see. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

They look like nails used as simple hangers. The ones in the corners are clearly driven into studs.

These can be removed without issue.